# Swift: How can I make an API call to a service but not wait for response

Tags: ios, swift, rest, api, okhttp

I have a collectionviewcontroller with a list notifications. Each time a notification is clicked, I send the user to the appropriate controller. What I'd like to do, is once a row is clicked, I'd like to make an API call and NOT wait for a response. This API call is just marking this row as READ, so I don't need to wait for the response from the server and I don't want the user to wait. I'm using okhttp to make API calls. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

OKHttp is designed for Android and there's no OKHttp on iOS platform.
You can use the OKHttp equivalent library [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). The request code by Alamofire is like this.

```swift
AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get").response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

By default, the code runs in the non-UI thread so that the user interaction will not be influenced.

Answer (score 1):

make your code request inside the background queue async like

```
      DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("This is run on the background queue")
        yourApiMethod() }
```